# I want 3 monitors with machine having 1 AMD 690/780 card and 1 VGA port via my motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, vga

I have 3 monitors that I would like to connect to my machine. The Machine is Windows 7 with a video card (AMD 690/780) with a DVI, USB connection, and an integrated VGA on the motherboard. I have tried all I know including making the motherboard the primary connection but that has yet to work. I did plug the 3 in but that resulted in one of the screens blinking rapidly while the others went to sleep. I would appreciate some help in getting my 3 monitors working. How can I accomplish this please? thanks in advance.

Comment: you can not use onboard VGA and AMD card at same time

Comment: what then can i use? What are my choices? How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Wait inventor to invented it!

Comment: What do you want three screens for? This isn't a pointless question, please try to answer it as accurately as possible, are you trying to display a single game across the three screens?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest buying a new video card that has three VGA ports or there are also video cards that specialize in multi-monitor set ups and come with a full compliment of adaptor ports.
I rate you should just try some on-line shopping :-)

Comment: Can an external video card do the job, in my case?

Comment: TripleHead2Go DP Edition would be best to use in this case.